# Fixing webcam in BlueStacks

Tags: webcam, bluestacks

As of now, my BlueStacks camera will not connect to anything showing the error,

> can not connect to the camera

After a while of looking around I did find the [BlueStacks camera troubleshooting guide](https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035514651-Troubleshooting-camera-issues-on-BlueStacks-4)

Which basically said that either my webcam is broken or BlueStacks just need to be restarted and it all will be fixed. My webcam is operational, and restarting the app didn't work. I also found some older questions that said BlueStacks didn't support webcams, but I assume that answer is just out of date. I'm on version `v4.210.0.1093`

Answer (score 3):

Ok the answer was to go into the windows registry editor and go to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\BlueStacks\Guests\Android\Config`. From there open the registry for camera. If it is 0 change it one and restart. If it is one change it to zero, restart change it back to one, and restart again